# check to see if TextInput has data and if so set IsClearButtonVisible true

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

First let me start off by saying I am not even sure if I am doing this right. I am trying to make "IsClearButtonVisible" Value="True" " if there is data in the "searchBox" once the use removes the text then I want to set "IsClearButtonVisible" Value="False". I think I need to add a binding, but not sure. Also I have the property of "searchBox" "var test = searchBox.value"

```
 <telerik:RadMaskedTextInput Name="searchBox" PreviewKeyUp="searchBox_KeyDown" Height="25" Width="200" Focusable="False">
        <telerik:RadMaskedTextInput.EmptyContent>
            <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox BorderBrush="Transparent" Height="26" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" >
                <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" Text="Enter Search Criteria here…" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox.WatermarkTemplate>
            </telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox>
        </telerik:RadMaskedTextInput.EmptyContent>
        <telerik:RadMaskedTextInput.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadMaskedTextInput}">
                <Setter Property="IsClearButtonVisible" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="TextMode" Value="PlainText"/>
                <Setter Property="Mask" Value=""/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="450"/>
            </Style>
        </telerik:RadMaskedTextInput.Style>
    </telerik:RadMaskedTextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were a textbox I'd do this.

You need to find out what the value of the searchbox is when empty. The trigger off that property and that value.

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="Text" TargetName="searchBox" Value="">
      <Setter Property="IsClearButtonVisible" Value="False"/>
   </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

If `value == null` when empty, then use

```
<Trigger Property="Value" TargetName="searchBox" Value="{x:Null}">
```